# How to have ASP.NET MVC look for view name that starts with an underscore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ide

My company has convention that partials must start with an underscore. However, when a partial is called from an action then the action is not named with an underscore which breaks the built in features of ASP.NET MVC. I'm hoping to solve two small issues:

1. Is there a way to configure ASP.NET MVC to search additional locations when it cannot find a view? In particular, I'd like to add logic that looks for a view of the same name as the action but with an underscore prefixed so that I can continue to write `return View();` without having to specify the name of the view.
2. Is there a way to enable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> shortcut that switches between an action and its view to also take advantage of this logic?

Comment: IMHO this question doesn't make any sense at all. I think it is much better for the performance to type view name then to force  web application to search it in a Shared  folder and somewhere else. I always type the view name explicitly. It prevents from taking old views with the same name that was obsoleted long ago but not deleted for some reasons.

Comment: @Serge Fair enough, but to be honest I care more about point number 2. Once you've gotten used to instantaneously moving back and forth between action and view with a keyboard shortcut it's such a drag to have to go open it manually.

Comment: @Serge FWIW though the performance issue is totally negligible unless you are doing something like rendering actions from a loop in a razor file.

Comment: About p.2. I can not tell about razor pages, I didn' t work very much with them. But when  it is  an MVC pattern, view not supposed to know which action will be used to open it. I ofen have several partions views for one action and there is a logic in model that selects which view should be snown. So I can' t imagine how swith between action and view could be arranged. Especially in many places i worked we had web disigners that made views and developers for the conrollers and actions logic.

Comment: @Serge Right, the second question doesn't have anything to do with the code in the actions or views. The shortcut is handled by the IDE. I think an extension or something like that could probably be written to handle this but I'm not very familiar with how that works.

Comment: I understand. I tried and got en error " unable to find a mathing view". This is what I was talking about.